# Why does config changes have to listen for orientation and screen size for orientation changes?

Tags: android, orientation, config

I read somewhere and took notes(forgot the source) that starting android 11 HONEYCOMB, to listen to orientation changes, you have to do android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize". My question why do you also have to listen to screen Size changes? I mean if you have a tablet  that is 400 by 600 px and you change the orientation, the new size will be 600 by 400 px. Can anyone explain the need to listen to screenSize?

Comment: This exists for situations which your app starts in a phone and then you connect it to a larger screen using an HDMI cable for instance. Now, your app has more space available and you can take advantage from that.

Comment: But in the situation I presented, how would screen size change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html):

> Note: If your application targets API level 13 or higher (as declared
>   by the `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` attributes), then you should
>   also declare the `"screenSize"` configuration, because it also changes
>   when a device switches between portrait and landscape orientations.

The [`onConfigurationChanged()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onConfigurationChanged%28android.content.res.Configuration%29) method is called if the activity declares that it will handle **all the configurations that are actually changing**. In Honeycomb, `orientation` is always accompanied by `screenSize` (and `screenSize` didn't exist previously). Therefore, if you only handle the `orientation` change, then the activity will be destroyed and recreated.

Also [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange), somewhat more explicit (but it's basically this reason).

Comment: yeah thx. Just curious how the screen size changes. The device stays at the same dimensions

Comment: @committedandroider Yes, but the width and height are swapped. That's considered a "size change" -- for example you might have `layout-w500dp` resources, and those only apply for one of the orientations.